# Is my sink trap too high?

Tags: drain-waste-vent, disposal, p-trap

Hello I renovated my kitchen and had plumbing moved and replaced.  Didn’t really think about the height of the waste pipe before cabinets sink and countertop went in.  With new sink and disposal installed, I’m afraid my p-trap is too high in order to line up with the waste drain.  This is what I did in the attached picture.  Is anything wrong with my setup?

[image]

Thanks everyone for your responses so far.  I’ve attached a slightly better pic which shows where the waste pipe is.  I will get dimensions once I get back tonight.  Nothing is glued yet so I can’t say it’s leaking.  I was hoping I could get some advice before it gets glued.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It isn't clear from the picture what's going on; would you add a picture and dimensions?

Comment: Are you asking because this set up is leaking?

Comment: We can't see where the drain pipe coming out of the wall is, but it appears that it is above the *disposer*. Hint: gravity is a critical issue for sewer and drain configuration...

Comment: I think the upstand is an AAV and presume the outflow is slightly below the end of the trap.

Comment: I don't really understand your concern. What doesn't line up? It looks perfectly normal to me, with the trap outlet somewhat lower than the disposer outlet.

Comment: You might be able to (and not know, as anyone who has not done so before often does not know) trim the end of the tailpiece entering the trap from the disposal to get the trap up a little higher. Not clear at present if it might be a little bit low, but looks like that could be the case (water does not run uphill.) There's a limit to how far you can trim without compromising the seal, butt there typically is some you can trim to slide it in further.

Comment: If the top of the elbow coming out of the trap is _higher_ than the top of the pipe where it enters the wall you should be fine. Preferably, you want a 1/4" per foot slope from the high end to the low end, but so long as you've got _some_ slope, you'll be OK.

Comment: As Ecnerwal suggested, I do have some room to shimmy the p-trap higher over the black tail piece coming from the disposal to make the trap higher but then the waste arm wouldn’t line up to the height of the waste drain or is it okay to cheat a little to get it to fit by tipping each pipe and fitting slightly up to try get it to line up?  I would think leaks could occur by doing so but I’m a newbie what do I know.

Answer (score 2):

With the new photo your trap appears to be perfect.
I find that traps have a fairly large operating range the important thing is that they hold water and yours will hold enough water to prevent sewer gas from backing up into the home. If you are having any issues let us know but with the air admittance valve and your setup I don’t see any problems.